# Get image name on delete in summernote editor

Tags: jquery, summernote

I have added a WYSWYG editor [sumernote](http://summernote.org/) and changed the settings to store the uploaded image on my server. By default the editor seem to base64 encode images to be stored in db. Now that I can upload image I need to be able to delete it when either the image is deleted from the post.

I am having the hardest time figuring out how to get the image name on delete button click with jQuery.

http://summernote.org/

Comment: can you create jsfiddle example for your question?

Comment: The above site has the editor as a demo. You can add an image and after you click on the image it brings up a popover with tool options. I'm interested in the delete button. When it is clicked I need to picked the image name in order to send it to my PHP script to delete this image from the server.

Comment: there is a link which can be helpful https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/605

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked one of the summernote Jsfiddle examples. It works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4pjphj3/)

You can try to use `onMediaDelete` event of summernote and `$target.context.dataset.filename` to get filename of image about to delete.

```
$(".summernote").summernote({
    onMediaDelete : function($target, editor, $editable) {
        alert($target.context.dataset.filename);         
        $target.remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: I've tried this code. It seems to be outdated a bit. First of all it needs callbacks: { } added and also I am not able to even locate any mention of onMediaDelete... http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#callbacks

Comment: did you try to add jquery on("click") event to delete button then call console.log($target[0].data("filename"))

Comment: @santa I forked one of summernote jsfidde examples. It works here => https://jsfiddle.net/b4pjphj3/

Comment: My bad, I was putting it outside initialized function... Thanks for your help!